# Why delete package command not working?

Tags: managed-package, unlocked-package, second-generation-packaging

I am trying to delete freshly created package, but error code says delete is not a valid command.

[image]

But it's available in official document

**Update**

Still not working even after installing pre-release plugin
[image]

Link: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_force_package.htm#cli_reference_delete

Comment: What version is your sfdx cli?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use prerelease version of the Salesforce CLI

You can install using the command below

```
sfdx plugins:install salesforcedx@pre-release
```

The functionality will be available once winter 21 v50.0 is generally available!

Also this will only work with the DevHub in prerelease orgs for now.

Comment: +1 In addition, you will not be able to actually *use* the command against an org that is still on Summer '20.

Comment: Still not working even after installing pre-release plugin

Comment: @Ragul what version is your devhub org?

Comment: @sfdcfox good points on devhub needs to be in winter21 as well else the delete ability is not provided by the api

Comment: current API Version 49.0

Comment: You need an org with v50.0 as Devhub else this won’t work